# Reorder list in specific lines

Tags: python

I have a file with lines like this:

```
r1  1   10
r2  10  1   #second bigger than third (10>1)
r3  5   2   #  ""       ""            (5>2)
r4  10  20
```

And I would like to reorder the lines with the second word bigger than the third, changing the [3] possition into [2] possition.

Desired output:

```
r1  1   10
r2  1   10
r3  2   5
r4  10  20
```

I have made a code that reorders the lines, but it only outputs the reordered lines, but not all the lines:

```
with open('test','r') as file, open('reorderedtest','w')as out:

for line in file:
    splitLine = line.split("\t")
    reorderedlist = [splitLine[0], splitLine[2], splitLine[1] ]
    if int(splitLine[1]) > int(splitLine[2]):
        str = "    "
        print str.join(reorderedlist)
```

And it only prints:

```
r2  1   10
r3  2   5
```

Any ideas to get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest modification to your existing code is this:

```
with open('test','r') as file, open('reorderedtest','w')as out:

for line in file:
    splitLine = line.split("\t")
    reorderedlist = [splitLine[0], splitLine[2], splitLine[1] ]
    if int(splitLine[6]) > int(splitLine[7]):
        str = "    "
        print str.join(reorderedlist)
    else:
        print line
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for any number of columns, where you have `r#` in the first column, then any number of numeric columns following.

```
with open('test.txt') as fIn, open('out.txt', 'w') as fOut:
    for line in fIn:
        data = line.split()
        first = data[0]    # r value
        values = sorted(map(int, data[1:]))   # sorts based on numeric value
        fOut.write('{} {}\n'.format(first, ' '.join(str(i) for i in values))  # write values back out
```

Resulting `out.txt` file

```
r1 1 10
r2 1 10
r3 2 5
r4 10 20
```